# How do I remove NA from a data frame with the intention of using sapply on the data frame

Tags: r, na, sapply

I have a data frame:

```
            colA           colB
1           15.3           1.76
2           10.8           1.34
3            8.1           1.27
4           19.5           1.47
5            7.2           1.27
6            5.3           1.49
7            9.3           1.31
8           11.1           1.09
9            7.5           1.18
10          12.2           1.22
11           6.7           1.25
12           5.2           1.19
13          19.0           1.95
14          15.1           1.28
15           6.7           1.52
16           8.6             NA
17           4.2           1.12
18          10.3           1.37
19          12.5           1.19
20          16.1           1.05
21          13.3           1.32
22           4.9           1.03
23           8.8           1.12
24           9.5           1.70
```

How would I be able to remove/change the value of all `NA`s such that when I use `sapply` (i.e. `sapply(x, mean)`), I am taking the mean of 24 rows in the case of `colA` and 23 columns for `colB`?

I understand that data frames have to have the same number of rows so using something like `na.omit()` would not work because it'd remove, in this case, row 16; I'd lose a row of data when I'm calculating the mean for `colA`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `colMeans(your_data, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I appreciate the responses, and while colMeans() works,  the requirement is to use sapply() on the data frame. With this in mind, I'm not sure how I would manipulate the data frame such that NA is changed/removed so that it's not taken into account when calculating the means of each column.

Comment: Then try `sapply(your_data, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass `na.rm = TRUE` and get the *mean*.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = c(NA, 1, 2))
apply(df, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#   A   B 
# 2.0 1.5
```

Comment: Since I'm using sapply(), I ended using sapply(df, mean, na.rm=T) and it worked. Marking this one as correct as it helped steer me in the right direction. Thanks!